# Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'number' Angular - Comunicación entre componentes

Tags: angular, variables, component

Estoy intentando crear en Angular una web que tiene un componente principal padre y como hijo tiene un componente menú y un segundo componente. Este componente menú tiene 3 botones y según a cual hagas click muestra el segundo componente que es hijo del componente principal.

Al intentarlo obtengo este error: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'number' ERROR in src/app/principal/principal.component.ts:18:18.

Este seria el código de menu.component.html

```
<div class="p-2">menu works!<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = activarComponente() >Gestión de usuarios</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) = activarComponente()>Gestión de productos</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = activarComponente()>Gestión de pedidos</button>
```

principal.component.html

```
<div class="pl-2 p-2">Componente principal
<login></login>
<menu class="pl-0"></menu>
<div [ngSwitch]="option">
    <gestion-usuarios *ngSwitchCase="0"></gestion-usuarios>
    <gestion-productos *ngSwitchCase="1"></gestion-productos>
    <gestion-pedidos *ngSwitchCase="2"></gestion-pedidos>
</div>
```

principal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'principal',
  templateUrl: './principal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./principal.component.css']
})
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnInit {


  option: number;
    @Output() opcion: number;
    
    
  
   activarComponente(option: number){
     this.option = option;
     this.opcion.emit(option);
   }
  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

gestion-productos.componnet.ts (seria igual para gestion-usuarios y gestion-pedidos pero cambiando el valor de opcion por 0 y 2 respectivamente)

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'gestion-productos',
  templateUrl: './gestion-productos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestion-productos.component.css']
})
export class GestionProductosComponent implements OnInit {

  opcion:number =1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Al hacer click en el boton del componente menu tiene que llegarle del componente hermano gestion-usuarios la variable opcion  y una vez que la tenga el componente menu pasarsela al componnete padre principal, pero no logro resolverlo.

Comment: creo que te falta implementar EventEmitter??

Comment: Me refiero, importas el componente pero no lo usas, no?

Comment: Es que no se bien donde usarlo en que ts ni como, podrias ayudarme por favor?

Comment: Si luego tengo un rato intento echarle un ojo!!

Comment: Ya esta solucionado ahora tengo otro problema pero creo un psot distinto gracias

Comment: Pon entonces la solución a este problema tú mismo agregando una respuesta. Puedes responder tus propias preguntas. Si no te deja ya creo qje te dejara en unos dias